# Sending money from Canada to the US

Tags: united-states, canada, money-transfer

I want to transfer money to an American bank account, but I am in Canada.  What is the cheapest way to do so?

[MetaFilter](http://ask.metafilter.com/83815/Sending-money-to-Canada-from-the-US) has:

1. [USPS mail order](http://www.usps.com/money/sendingmoney/sendmoneyinternationally.htm) - $700 limit, $4 charge
2. Vanilla wire transfer (My bank requires it be done in person and charges $30 per transaction, limit $3000)
3. Cheque: ($40 fee?)

Any gotcha's (i.e. HIDDEN FEES) and / recommended methods?

Answer (score 8):

XE.com will do an ACH transfer for no fee, and they'll give you a better exchange rate than your bank.  I use them for converting CAD/USD.

Comment: Thanks.  Does xe.com impose a maximum transfer size?

Comment: @nealmcb I seem to recall a limit of $10,000. You can get that adjusted by calling them.