# How can my Canadian friend send me money in the United States?

Tags: united-states, canada, money-transfer

I purchased some merchandise for a friend who lives in Canada. She wants to pay me for these items. What is the best way for her to do this?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/5370/7590)? The answers there might be exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways to transfer money from Canada to US, so the only problem choosing the most reliable, cheap, and fast way.

1. Services: [Western Union](http://www.westernunion.ca), [MoneyGram](https://www.moneygram.com) . Fast, but service fee is too high. Better to avoid.
2. Wire transfer. several days, fee depending on bank
3. money order or bank draft (fee depending on bank)
4. personal check (can be kept on hold in receiving bank)
5. cash in envelope (if amount is not big (

   [paypal](https://www.paypal.com). If you both have account there it's free, only conversion rate is not best. But anyway I think it's best choice.

PS: Interac e-Transfer is unfortunately only available inside Canada. I know nothing about XE.com, so I can't recommend it. There should be other ways to transfer money.

Comment: Correction, a Wire Transfer is INSTANT. If a bank tells you that a wire takes days, it's because they are using what's called ACH - different method of transit.